# chomre.storage returns undefined in localhost when extension created with create-react-app

Tags: reactjs, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-storage

I am trying to use `chrome.storage` API. However, when I perform a `console.log` of `chrome.storage` in my browsers console, both my localhost and built extension returns `undefined`.

There is an extension which I know makes use of `chrome.storage` API and when I do the same it returns an object with correct information (looks like storage is the only thing that is different compared with both extensions). I have implemented `chrome.storage.sync.set` and `chrome.storage.sync.get` but I experience issues relating to `chrome.storage` being undefined.

My `manifest.json` file looks like below

```
{
  "name": "Name of application",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "description": "A plain text description",
  "icons": {
    "32": "logo_32.png",
    "64": "logo_64.png",
    "128": "logo_128.png",
    "256": "logo_256.png"
  },
  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "logo_32.png"
  },
  "author": "Author name",
  "chrome_url_overrides": {
    "newtab": "index.html"
  },
  "permissions": [
    "storage",
    "http://localhost/*"
  ]
}
```

When I console.log just chrome (`console.log(chrome)`) I get returned object, which is different from the build extension.

I have searched around and can not find a solution. Most answers I have found simply state checking the permissions in the manifest file.

As I created the extension with `create-react-app`, is there any other configuration I need to change in order to be able to use `chrome.storage`?

**Update**
So instead of reloading extension from extensions, I deleted the extension and then added the extension back. This allows me to access `chrome.storage` when built. However, for my localhost, I still get `chrome.storage` is undefined. Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: chrome.storage uses asynchronous callbacks so it doesn't return anything, look for usage examples.

Comment: Yes, I know. There is an extension which I know make uses of chrome.storage API; I can console.log(chrome.storage) in the browsers console and it returns an object with correct information. I would expect the same behaviour for my extension, however, mine returns undefined. While implementing chrome.storage.sync.set and browserObject.storage.sync.get, I experience issues relating to chrome.storage being undefined. So I must be missing something. I thought maybe with create-react-app there additional configs I may need to set up as I have not ejected my app

Comment: Ah, sounds like you need to declare in some config that `chrome` is a built-in global object. I don't know how but I imagine it should be a known problem.

Comment: I think it's just eslint complaining about chrome not being defined so you have to adjust that. Try adding /* globals chrome */ on top of the file you use the storage api in.

Comment: So I already have /* globals chrome */. Turns out I had to completely remove the extension and then reselect the build from extensions tab. However, on my localhost, it cannot access chrome.storage. Is there any way to make it work on my localhost. I have added localhost to permissions

Comment: `chrome` API is available only inside extension context which means chrome-extension:// URL.

Comment: @wOxxOm So there is no way to develop on localhost? Is the only solution to manually build and `Load unpacked` in `chrome:extensions`? I am asking since I would like to somehow test my extension but Cypress does not allow navigation to `chrome://` and I simply cannot figure out how to test the extension with Jest or Mocha & Chai. I even tried using Puppeteer & Jest-Puppeteer, but it does not give coverage reports that are meaningful (only 1-2 lines are analyzed due to the build since you must load the extension to puppeteer). Any suggestion would be much appreciated.